# Can I have two variables in CartoCSS?

Tags: cartocss

Within CartoDB my CartoCSS looks something like

```
#table_copy_1 [ lease_rate <= 55.15] {
   marker-width: 35.0; marker-fill: #081B47     
}
```

Can I add another variable (size) so that the display filters by both lease_rate and size? My idea is that it would look like this:

```
#table_copy_1 [ lease_rate <= 55.15, size <= 40000] {
   marker-width: 35.0; marker-fill: #081B47     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, combining multiple filters is allowed. For example:

```
#cities {
  [zoom>=4][population>1000000],
  [zoom>=5][population>500000],
  [zoom>=6][population>100000] {
    text-name: [name];
    text-face-name: 'Arial Regular';
  }
}
```

from https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/selectors/ (found by googling `cartocss tutorial multiple conditions`)